# Automatically run tests on deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, capistrano

Is there a way to have capistrano run unit tests on my Rails app when I run `cap deploy`, and fail if they don't pass? I know this can and should be done by the deployer, but I'd love it to be automatic. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I ended up using [this](https://gist.github.com/1097695) as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This capistrano task will run the unit tests on the server being deployed, in production mode:

```
desc "Run the full tests on the deployed app." 
task :run_tests do
 run "cd #{release_path} && RAILS_ENV=production rake && cat /dev/null > log/test.log" 
end
```

Found the solution here: http://marklunds.com/articles/one/338

:D

Comment: The solution you posted runs the test on the production server. I don't think majority would be doing tht..

Answer (score 4):

This setup will run your tests locally before deploying.

**Capistrano task**, e.g. *lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake*

```rb
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Run test suite before deployment'
  task :test_suite do
    run_locally do
      execute :rake, 'test'
    end
  end
end
```

**Capistrano config,** *config/deploy.rb*

```rb
before 'deploy:starting', 'deploy:test_suite'
```

Works in Capistrano v3.x

Answer (score 0):

*config/deploy.rb*

```
# Path of tests to be run, use array with empty string to run all tests
set :tests, ['']

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Runs test before deploying, can't deploy unless they pass"
  task :run_tests do
    test_log = "log/capistrano.test.log"
    tests = fetch(:tests)
    tests.each do |test|
      puts "--> Running tests: '#{test}', please wait ..."
      unless system "bundle exec rspec #{test} > #{test_log} 2>&1"
        puts "--> Aborting deployment! One or more tests in '#{test}' failed. Results in: #{test_log}"
        exit;
      end
      puts "--> '#{test}' passed"
    end
    puts "--> All tests passed, continuing deployment"
    system "rm #{test_log}"
  end

  # Only allow a deploy with passing tests to be deployed
  before :deploy, "deploy:run_tests"

end
```

Run it with with

```
cap production deploy:run_tests
```